# Angular populate ng-repeat and ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

In  my app I have a widget that is used on multiple pages and the selections made on the widgets are to be transferred between pages. So if I select something in the widget on the homepage and click 'continue' which then takes me to a new page, the widget should be pre-populated with the selections made on the homepage.

My widget follows the following format (although not exact for simplistic explanations):

```
<li ng-repeat="device in devices track by $index">
    <select name="model[{{$index}}]" ng-model="selectedManufacturer" ng-options"...">
    <select name="model[{{$index}}]" ng-model="selectedModel" ng-options"...">
</li>
```

It's the values of the ng-models inside the repeat statement that contain the key data in the widget that needs to be transferrable.

The number of devices needs to be transferrable too but that will be easy as `devices` is just an array of numbers so `selectedModel.length -1` will equal the value of `devices` on the secondary pages.

Is it possible to pre-populate the values of ng-models?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can prepopulate values of `ng-model`s (or any scope variable) using [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit#example)

Comment: How do I prepopulate each instance of the ng-model? If on the homepage I select 3 handsets, that's 3 x selectedModel that need to be prefilled.

Comment: You mean something like this? `<select name="model[{{$index}}]" ng-model="selectedManufacturer" ng-init="..." ng-options"...">`

Comment: Yes, how does the JS know to split the results between all models?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pre-populate the value in your ng-model which would mean a default/inital value in your drop-down. This can be achieved by doing the following:-

```
$scope.selectedManufacturer = listOfManufacturer[0];
$scope.selectedModel = listOfSelectedModel[0];
```